# Restore unstaged changes lost on branch switch with IntelliJ / PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm as IDE and did edit some files without commiting them to VCS nor staging them. Unfortunately I switched the branch I was working in to one where the files don't exist. There was a notice popping up, probably telling me I would lose my changes, but by accidentally hitting the keyboard at the same time I confirmed that notice immediately.

Is there a way to restore my lost changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is:

- switch back to the branch you did work in
- open each file you did work in. Within each file

  - right click to open local history of that file
  - on the left hand side selecte the time when you switched branches first
  - copy from previous code to current code

You can even restore files which don't exist anymore: just create them again in the same folder and with exact same name as previously and use the same technic as above!

Comment: That's a solution, but I'll add that one could see the local history of an entire package, say, "main". There changes are displayed in batches, that will save some time.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! I had to look up the file names in the logs though, because I had about 30 of them changed before I lost it.

Answer (score 5):

To see the complete history of all files, you can right click on your project and go to **Local History -> Show history** (using IntelliJ 2021.3). From there you can copy the parts you need. To get back the complete file(s):
Select(multi-selection possible) + right click the file(s) and click on **Revert selection**

Answer (score 4):

For me PhpStorm saved the lost changes in the Shelf. To restore your changes from there, complete these steps:

1. Open the "Commit" menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)
2. In the opened window go to the "Shelf" tab. If the window doesn't have enough horizontal space, it could be placed under "Show hidden tabs" button near the tab name, you can find the "Shelf" tab there.
3. Select a respective line with "Uncommited changes before ..." that you wish to restore and click "Unshelve Silently" button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). You can also choose to restore files selectively and do the same process.
4. Make sure that your changes are restored and commit them if you need to.
5. If you completed the previous step, you can delete the shelved changes, as they are not needed anymore - select, then right click and "Delete" (or select and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>).

Comment: I consider this the best approach, works for intelij as well, you actually get access to the patch that was aborted this way.